# Access inner items while defining controller sencha

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, toggle, fieldset

I have a view file with panel, which contains a fieldset, which in turn contains 4 toggle buttons. I have controller file which generates an output on change of value of toggle button,

[Controller.js](http://pastebin.com/zpDtGjVb)

[View.js](http://pastebin.com/vFcnx1BE)

Currently as you can see, I am getting individual refrences to each toggle button, and handling the change event. Is there any way I can create a reference to fieldset and then use it for referring the toggle button (it's inner items), and handle toggle button 'change' event, programatically?

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of `control` is a selector, so it should bind listener to each selected item from the view (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control). 
 Something like this:

```
Ext.define('test.controller.sortList', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['test.view.sortList'], 

    init: function () { 
        var me = this;
        me.control({
            'fieldset #sortFirstName': {
                change: me.sortFirstName
            }
        });
    },

    sortFirstName: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('Value of this toggle has changed:', (newValue) ? 'ON' : 'OFF');    
    }
});
```

Or you can add listeners to this events in the view and fire your custom events with ready to use params:

```
{
    xtype: 'togglefield',
    id: 'sortFirstName',
    value:1,
    label: 'First Name',
    labelWrap:true,
    labelWidth: '50%',
    listeners: [
        change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
            // making smth with params
            this.fireEvent('sortFirstName', param);
        },
        scope: me
    ]
}
```

And manage them inside controller like this:

```
me.control({
    'viewxtype': {
         sortFirstName: me.sortFirstName,
         sortSomethingMore: me.sortSmthMore
    }
});
```